# Import Header from Main Project into Sub Project

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to import the header from my main view controller into a class that resides in a subproject within my main project.

When I reference a class in the subproject from a class in my main project I can simple include it like this

```
#import <subproject/class.h>
```

How can I do this reverse? I tried, but it does not work

```
#import <mainproject/class.h>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be introducing circular dependancies like this (besides, unless your main project is a framework, this won't work).  If the two projects depend on each other that much, then merge them.

Comment: My client came with this setup. I'm hesitant to restructure the whole thing. But yes, it's not a good setup at all.